# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Microsoft Account OAuth2 sign-on stop to work after update the Microsoft.Owin packages from v3.0.1 to v3.1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication

I have updated the following Nuget packages from **v3.0.1** to **v3.1.0**:

- *Microsoft.Owin*
- *Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb*
- *Microsoft.Owin.Security*
- *Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies*
- *Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google*
- *Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount*

And after these updates the following issue is displayed when I try to authenticate using a Microsoft Account:

**Correlation ID: 1a411cc0-446c-42bb-8659-cdd7dd9e6199**

**AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope wl.emails is not valid.**

Important notes:

- This issue is only happening when I try to use a Microsoft Account for authenticating. There is no issue when I use a Google account for authenticating it
- When I do the downgrade for the v3.0.1 the Microsoft Account authentication back to work again

Does anyone know if something has changed in Microsoft authentication on *Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount v3.1.0* that I have to change in my source code?

Here are the **Startup.Auth.cs** from the System:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount;
using Owin;

namespace IRIS
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions { ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120), LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login") };
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(cookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions { ClientId = "<MyGoogleClientId>", ClientSecret = "<MyGoogleClientSecret>" });
            app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions { ClientId = "<MyMicrosoftClientId>", ClientSecret = "<MyClientSecret>", Scope = { "wl.emails" } });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue and have not found any issue around it.Running 3.0.1 works but 3.1.0 fails